# RavenDb : Search occurrences in text is slow

Tags: ravendb

I would like to find the occurrences of a word in a text.
I have a class like this

```
public class Page
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have  my index like this :

```
class Pages_SearchOccurrence : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Page, Pages_SearchOccurrence.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string PageId { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string Word { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public Pages_SearchOccurrence()
    {
        Map = pages => from page in pages
                       let words = page.Content
                                       .ToLower()
                                       .Split(new string[] { " ", "\n", ",", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       from w in words
                       select new
                       {
                           page.Content,
                           PageId = page.Id,
                           Count = 1,
                           Word = w
                       };


        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by new { PageId = result.PageId, result.Word } into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Content = g.First().Content,
                                PageId = g.Key.PageId,
                                Word = g.Key.Word,
                                Count = g.ToList().Count()
                            };

        Index(x => x.Content, Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

Finally, my query is like this :

```
    using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                RavenQueryStatistics stats;
                var occurence = session.Query<Pages_SearchOccurrence.ReduceResult, Pages_SearchOccurrence>()
                    .Statistics(out stats)
                    .Where(x => x.Word == "works")
                    .ToList();


            }
```

But I realize that RavenDb is very slow (or my query is not good   )
stats.IsStale = true and raven studio take too much time and give only few results.
I have 1000 document “Pages” with a  content of 1000 words per Page .
Why is my query not okay  and how can I  find the occurrences in a page ?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you not relying on Lucene for this? It does have full-text indexing and querying capabilities you know. Am I missing something?

Comment: You may find this helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774036/search-inside-an-attachment-in-ravendb

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You should set the Content field as Analyzed and use RavenDB's Search() operator. The slowness is most likely because of the amount of un-optimized work your index code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had found a partial result.

Perhaps I'm not clear : my goal is to find the occurrences of a word in the page. 
I search the hits count of a word in the page and I would like to order by this count.

I changed my index like this :

```
 class Pages_SearchOccurrence : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Page, Pages_SearchOccurrence.ReduceResult>{

 public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string PageId { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }
        public string Word { get; set; }
    }

     public Pages_SearchOccurrence()
    {
        Map = pages => from page in pages
                       let words = page.Content.ToLower().Split(new string[] { " ", "\n", ",", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       from w in words
                       select new
                       {
                           page.Content,
                           PageId = page.Id,
                           Count = 1,
                           Word = w
                       };

        Index(x => x.Content, Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x => x.PageId, Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
    }
```

Finally, my new query looks like this :

```
  using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {

                var query = session.Query<Pages_SearchOccurrence.ReduceResult, Pages_SearchOccurrence>()
                   .Search((x) => x.Word, "works")
                   .AggregateBy(x => x.PageId)
                   .CountOn(x => x.Count)
                   .ToList()
                   .Results
                   .FirstOrDefault();

                 var listFacetValues = query.Value.Values;
                 var finalResult = listFacetValues.GroupBy(x => x.Hits).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).Take(5).ToList();


            }
```

The *finalResult* gives me a group of *Facetvalue* which have a property *Hits*

( the properties *Hits* and *Count* of my *FacetValue* are the same here )

The *Hits* property gives me the result that I want  but for me this code is not correct and ravendb studio doesn't like this too.

Do you have a better solution ?